# WCF authentication service via Json

Tags: wcf, json, authorization

I have built a web service (WCF) as part of our company product, to support mobile devicies. The service is exposed via SOAP and is consumed by Android and Windows Phone 7 clients. Now we are spreading and need to add support for iPhone clients and those lazy iPhone developers are complaing, that they won't use SOAP, because its terrible, microsoftish, bloatware and there is no sufficient framework for that, etc etc and JSON ftw!

As it is WCF it was easy to create json api for this web service (new interface and little changes in web.config, love WCF!), the only problem is that I am using the built-in [WCF Authentication service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386582.aspx) for authorization and this service is of course exposed via SOAP and I didn´t find a way to make it REST with json. So is there a way to somehow make it RESTful and consume/respond json?

My actual plan is to make another auth service, that will internally just call the existing WCF one via SOAP, but I don't like this workaround. I assume that, if there is not a way to make the WCF one RESTfull, later or sooner, I end up writing the auth service, which in my opinon will not be that hard.